# how to refresh selectize options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I have an ajax call that change a select element options every success, i loop through the data and put it into a string

```
$.each(value, function(i, trx){
    trxListOptions += "<option value="+trx+">";
    trxListOptions += trx;
    trxListOptions += "</option>"
}
```

then i appended the html string into select element

```
$("#selectizeTrx").append(trxListOptions);
```

then i initialize selectize

```
$("selectizeTrx").selectize();
```

this works, but only for the first time, after the second ajax call that change every select options, selectize options wont show the new options, it still shows the old options.

how to refresh/reload selectize options so it adjust to original select element ??

Answer (score 2):

Try this before appending and initializing

```
 $('#selectizeTrx').selectize()[0].selectize.destroy();
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/m06c56y0/22/)

Comment: what this code do ? after i add this line, the new option appear, but the old options are still there, so it stacked.

Comment: that should have not happened check the fiddle

Comment: yeah, i dont know why my options are stacked

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($('select.#selectizeTrx'),function (i, el) {
    el.selectize.destroy();//destroy your selectize
})
var allOptions =  $('select.#selectizeTrx').html();//get current select options.
allOptions += newOptions; //combine your new options and current options
$('select.#selectizeTrx').html(allOptions);//set all options
$('select.#selectizeTrx').selectize({

});//and selectize.
```

note: destroy method can remove select options. Because get current options and combine new options.